# Reveal li elements "radially"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

Following function reveals `<li>` elements one by one from left to right.

```
$.fn.fadeInEach = function(duration,callback){
    function fadeIn(i,elements,duration,callback){
        if(i >= elements.length)
            typeof callback == 'function' && callback();
        else
            elements.eq(i).fadeIn(duration,function(){
               fadeIn(i+1,elements,duration,callback);
            });        
    }
    fadeIn(0,this,duration,callback);
    return this;
}
```

Executing like that

```
 $('.ftr-social-icons ul li').fadeInEach(200);
```

Lets say we have 9 `<li>` elements. What I want to get is, first reveal 5th element, then 4th and 6th, then 3th and 7th...

If there is 8 `<li>` elements, reveal at first 4th and 5th, and so on...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a plugin example.  Does this help?

HTML:

```
<h2>Colors</h2>
<ol>
    <li>Red</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
    <li>Yellow</li>
    <li>Green</li>
    <li>Blue</li>
    <li>Indigo</li>
    <li>Violet</li>
</ol>

    <h2>Directions</h2>
<ol>
    <li>North</li>
    <li>East</li>
    <li>South</li>
    <li>West</li>
</ol>
```

JavaScript:

```
$.fn.fadeInFromMiddle = function(duration, callback) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var radialFade = function($items, duration, indices) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                var i, max, index;

                for(i=0, max=indices.length; i<max; i++) {
                    index = indices[i]
                    $items.eq(index).animate({ 'opacity' : 1 });
                    indices[i] = i === 0 ? index - 1 : index + 1;
                }

                if(indices.length === 1) {
                    indices.push(indices[0]+2);
                }
                if(indices[0] >= 0) {
                    radialFade($items, duration, indices);
                }
                else if( typeof callback === "function" ) {
                    callback();
                }

            }, duration);
        };

        // hide all
        var $items = $(this).children().css('opacity',0);

        // show from middle
        var size = $items.size(),
            indices = [ Math.ceil( size / 2)-1 ]; // starting point
        if( size % 2 === 0 ) { indices.push( indices[0]+1 ); }
        radialFade($items, duration, indices); // second param is delay between fades

    });
};
$(function() { 
    $('ol').fadeInFromMiddle(300);

})
```

Comment: nice, it's a cool effect...here's a fiddle using your answer [example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/eShj4/)

Comment: Thank you!  I actually converted this to a jQuery plugin and forked your example into mine.  I also added an odd example as well as an even one. [New Example](http://jsfiddle.net/thejase/B5YXD/2/)

Comment: Thx for answer, but my li menu is Horizontal not vertical, and I can't see any effect. All appearing at once wit your function

Comment: Good... what did you have to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Define a javascript array out side the function with values of ints which represent the order of fadein. then use elements of that array instead of using directly "i" variable.

E.g:

```
var fadeOrder = new Array(5, 4, 6, 3, 7, 2, 1);

$.fn.fadeInEach = function(duration,callback){
    function fadeIn(i,elements,duration,callback){
        if(fadeOrder[i] >= elements.length)
            typeof callback == 'function' && callback();
        else
            elements.eq(fadeOrder[i]).fadeIn(duration,function(){
               fadeIn(i+1,elements,duration,callback);
            });        
    }
    fadeIn(0,this,duration,callback);
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up a quick solution but I haven't done any tests so I highly recommend you take it for a quick spin around the block. The basic logic is there. If you need anymore info, let me know!

Here's the code:

```
$.fn.fadeInEach = function( duration, callback ){
  var length = this.length,
      middle = Math.floor( length / 2 ) + 1,
      offset = 0,
      flip = 1,
      duration = duration,
      callback = callback,
      that = this;

  function chainFade(){
    if( offset < length )
        that.eq( middle + offset * flip )
            .fadeIn( duration, function(){
                offset++;
                flip *= -1;
                chainFade();
            });
    else
        typeof callback == 'function' && callback();
  }
  chainFade();

  return this;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

set up an array of elements that are not yet visible then fade the middle element, remove it from the array, recurse until empty?